# Clearing array from laravel session (laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm currently setting an array of tokens in a user's session on a laravel site, and the session successfully sets the array (called `tokenArray`) which shows in the debug bar for the session as expected:

```
    if (!is_null($user) && $user->active) {

        Auth::login($user);

        Session::put('Tokens',$tokenArray);

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());

    }
```

The issue is that when I logout successfully and get redirected to the sign in page the array of tokens still shows in the session on the debug bar.

I would think it would be destroyed by default but is there a way that I need to flush the array specifically? I have a listener on the logout event, so if I need to I could try something there.

SHould this be cleared by default though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `Session::flush();` on your logout method to delete all session data or.

```
Session::forget('tokens');
```

to delete only the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use session helper.

```
session()->forget('tokens');
```

To delete all session data call following method.

```
 session()->flush();
```